# How do I show/hide datatips on a chart with a secondary series

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

I have a line chart with a column chart as a secondary series. When I roll over the line, the datatips appear. However, if I move the mouse to a spot where a column appears while still on the line, the data tip item appears for the line AND the column. How do I get it so that I only show datatips for the line but not the column?

```
<mx:AreaChart id="areachart" dataProvider="{data}" showDataTips="true" >
    <mx:series>

    <mx:AreaSeries id="areaSeries" xField="date" yField="volume" >
    </mx:AreaSeries>


    <mx:ColumnSeries id="secondSeries" xField="date" yField="name" >
    </mx:ColumnSeries>

    </mx:series>

</mx:AreaChart>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subclass AreaChart and override findDataPoints method to filter out the data points you don't want:

```
public class CustomAreaChart extends AreaChart
{
    public override function findDataPoints(x:Number, y:Number):Array
    {
        var originalDPs : Array = super.findDataPoints(x, y);
        var filteredDPs : Array = [];

        for each (var hd : HitData in originalDPs)
        {
            if (hd.chartItem.element is AreaSeries)
                filteredDPs.push(hd);
        }

        return filteredDPs;
    }
}
```

And then use this new class instead of AreaChart.

Answer (score 5):

Alternatively you can set the interactive property of the column to false:

```
   <mx:ColumnSeries id="secondSeries" xField="date" yField="name" interactive="false">
   </mx:ColumnSeries>
```

This will prevent the columns from responding to mouse input.

Comment: That works too, can't believe I missed that property! And it's much more elegant...

Comment: Hey, it was hard to find, don't be so hard on yourself!